# React why does eventListener runs twice unless terminate on useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

just got interesting phenomenon while coding.

I was trying to send request when I press 'enter' and found that 'keypress' eventListener runs twice.

so I figured out when I terminate keypress eventListener when component unmounts, the problem got fixed, but I just cant understand why this happens.

```
const inputRef = useRef(null);
    const fileRef = useRef(null);
    const [files, setFile] = useState([]);

    const sendMessage = useCallback(() => {
        if (inputRef.current.value === '' && files.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        console.log('f', inputRef.current.value, files);
        if (files.length === 0) {
            AxiosClient.post('/general-msg', {
                orderId,
                recipient,
                content: inputRef.current.value
            });
            inputRef.current.value = '';
        } else {
            const messagePackage = new FormData();
            messagePackage.append('orderId', orderId);
            messagePackage.append('recipient', recipient);
            messagePackage.append('content', inputRef.current.value);

            files.map((file) => {
                return messagePackage.append('file', file);
            });

            AxiosClient.post('/message', messagePackage, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            });
            inputRef.current.value = '';
            setFile([]);
        }
    }, [files, inputRef, orderId, recipient]);

    const registerSendingTrigger = useCallback(
        (e) => {
            console.log('heelo');
            if (e.code === 'Enter') {
                console.log('sending...'); // sending logs twice unless I write below
                sendMessage();
            }
        },
        [sendMessage]
    );
    useEffect(() => {
        if (inputRef.current) {
            inputRef.current.removeEventListener('keypress', registerSendingTrigger);

            inputRef.current.addEventListener('keypress', registerSendingTrigger);
        }

        return () => inputRef.current.removeEventListener('keypress', registerSendingTrigger); // this part!!!!!!!!

        // why does send request gets twice when I delete return state??
    }, [inputRef, registerSendingTrigger]);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (fileRef) {
            fileRef.current.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                if (!e.target.files[0]) {
                    return;
                }
                setFile((current) => {
                    return [...current, e.target.files[0]];
                });
            });
        }
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useEffect is executed every time something in the dependency-array changes value. This means that in your case it will add another event-listener when `registerSendingTrigger` changes it value.

The misconception here is that useEffect represents the `mount` and `unmount` of React. It works like that if you have an empty dependency array, but will be executed more often when it is used with dependencies.

Check this for more information:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects